# Why jQuery .data() function is not accessing HTML5 camel-case data attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button in my web page:

```
<button class="slideToggle" data-slideToggle="slider">SlideToggle</button>
```

When this button is clicked I am trying to access the data that is stored inside the data-slideToggle attribute by useing the following code, but I get nothing.

```
$('body').on('click', '.slideToggle', function(){
    alert($(this).data('slideToggle'));
});
```

but it works when I use:

```
alert($(this).attr('data-slideToggle'));
```

This problem occurs when I use camel-case data attribute. I am very new to HTML5 and jQuery and I can not figure out what is going wrong with it.

Comment: You can access it as "slideToggle" via `.data()` if you call it `data-slide-toggle` in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the previous answers miss one thing: you actually can work with existing HTML structure. Consider this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.slideToggle', function(){
    alert($(this).data('slidetoggle')); // wait, what?
});
```

To understand what happens here, it's crucial to check the following lines in [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c869a1ef8a031342e817a2c063179a787ff57239/src/data.js#L27):

```
name = "data-" + key.replace( rmultiDash, "-$1" ).toLowerCase();
data = elem.getAttribute( name );
```

See, jQuery here follows the convention of Dataset API, converting the `fooBar` property into `data-foo-bar` name of the element's attribute.

In your case, that converts `'slideToggle'` to `'data-slide-toggle'` - and there's no such attribute in your HTML, apparently.

However, `data('slidetoggle')` works fine, as `getAttribute` by default performs a *case-insensitive* search among Element's attributes. Therefore, you might even wrote that one as...

```
<button data-sLiDeToGgLe="l33t!"></button>
```

... and it still [**would have worked**](http://jsfiddle.net/22uhm7r2/). )

Still, I'd rather recommend following the Dataset API convention, breaking camelCased `complexWord` data attributes into hyphenated `complex-word` notation.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not how you should use it. You can only use lowercase attributes and that's why it isn't working for you.

Change `<button class="slideToggle" data-slideToggle="slider">SlideToggle</button>` 
to

```
<button class="slideToggle" data-slidetoggle="slider">SlideToggle</button>
```

and access it like `alert($(this).data('data-slidetoggle'));`

`attr` works on any custom attribute so it works there too, but `data` has some rules to follow.

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) says

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no uppercase ASCII letters.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this

- The data-* attributes consist of two parts:

  - The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must be at least one character long after the prefix "data-"
  - The attribute value can be any string

Use as

```
<button class="slideToggle" data-slidetoggle="slider">SlideToggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you add camalCase Attribute; on browser it is converted into lower case; so you have to access it through

```
$(this).attr('data-slidetoggle')
```

and as per w3c school (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

The data-* attributes consist of two parts:

1. The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and
   must be at least one character long after the prefix "data-"
2. The attribute value can be any string