# How to make simple fade effect or slow animation onmouseover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, mouseevent

Like in the topic. My code looks like:

```
    $('li a').mouseover(function () {
    var rhomboidImg = $(this).data('rhomboid-img');
    $('#img-nav-rhomboid').css('background', 'url(' + rhomboidImg + ') no-repeat ');
    $('#img-nav-rhomboid img').delay(2000).fadeIn();
});
```

And here is html:

```
<nav class="menu-closed">
            <div id="img-nav-rhomboid" class="nav-rhomboid"></div>
            <ul class="menu-list"> 
                <li class="menu-accent-border"><img src="img/menu-mrowka.jpg" alt="Materiały Budowlane"/><li>
                <li><a href="mrowka.html" data-rhomboid-img="img/nav1.jpg">Mrówka Wszystko dla domu</a></li>
                <li><a href="instal-metal.html" data-rhomboid-img="img/nav2.jpg">Sklep instalacyjno-metalowy</a></li>
                <li class="menu-accent-border2"><img src="img/menu-psb.jpg" alt="Materiały Budowlane"/><li>
                <li><a href="bud-opalenica.html" data-rhomboid-img="img/nav3.jpg">Magazyn materiałów budowlanych Opalenica</a></li>
                <li><a href="bud-nowytomysl.html" data-rhomboid-img="img/nav4.jpg">Magazyn materiałów budowlanych Nowy Tomyśl</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-rhomboid-img="img/nav5.jpg">Magazyn materiałów budowlanych Grodzisk Wlkp.</a></li>
                <li class="menu-accent-border3"><a href="" data-rhomboid-img="img/nav6.jpg">Centrum ogrodnicze OPALFLORA</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-rhomboid-img="img/nav7.jpg">Betoniarnia</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-rhomboid-img="img/nav8.jpg">Uścięcice</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

When I hover on li element it should change the picture, but with some animation.

Comment: Show the HTML please and explain what exact problem you are having.

Comment: [warning on jquery's .data() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766574/why-jquery-data-function-is-not-accessing-html5-camel-case-data-attribute)

Comment: I have just added :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only trying to create a fade-in animation on hover you might as well want to use CSS

```
.rhomboid-img{
    opacity: 0;
}

.rhomboid-img:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 2s all ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged css, I am going to give you some CSS code that will work for this:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
0% {
    opacity: 0
}
to {
    opacity: 1
}
}
.fadeIn {
   animation-name: fadeIn
}
```

This above is courtesy of https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

```
.rhomboid-img {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
```

This above will delay the fade in for your desired 2000 or two seconds. Just make sure you use both .fadeIn and .rhomboid-img classes.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for animate.css, I could have missed part of the code. You also could link animate.min.css to your site and use the classes that way as well.